# Ориентации устройства в iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

всем привет!
почитал документацию по IOS и так понимаю что для 5 и 6 версии управление елементами интерфейса при изменении ориентации устройства отличается. Мне пока не понята логика autolayout, но я вижу что в настройках каждого .xib  галку можно снять и отключить эту функцию. Я так понимаю что предыдущая система (для ios 5)  устаревает? Я тестирую на симуляторе и все работает со старой системой, нет возможности протестировать на устройстве. Если я оставлю все с отключенным autolayout ,будет ли старая система работать на ios 6-7-...  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> всем привет! почитал документацию по IOS и так понимаю что для 5 и 6 версии управление елементами интерфейса при изменении ориентации устройства отличается. Мне пока не понята логика autolayout,

autolayout и ориентация не особо связаны, основное предназначение первого - чтобы на разных пропорциях экрана все было хорошо и введено оно было из-за выхода 5-го айфона с другой пропорцией, а разная ориентация просто тоже имеет разные пропрции, но работает ли приложение в разных ориентациях определяется отдельно (причем в нескольких местах - весь проект в целом + в каждом контроллере еще можно задать что из поддерживаемых ориентаций в нем работает)

> но я вижу что в настройках каждого .xib  галку можно снять и отключить эту функцию. Я так понимаю что предыдущая система (для ios 5) устаревает?

в принципе да, но некоторые люди хотят чтобы работало на текущей -2 мажорных версии, это уже от ваших заказчиков зависит. на вскидку выкидывание ios 5 отрежет только первый айпад - все остальное либо не обновлялось даже до нее, либо обновляется до 6 (не помню как там с айподами)

> Я тестирую на симуляторе и все работает со старой системой, нет возможности протестировать на устройстве. Если я оставлю все с отключенным autolayout ,будет ли старая система работать на ios 6-7-... ?

Будет, но стоит погонять тесты - системы все-таки отличаются весьма прилично

Comment: спасибо, все понял. как наберу кармы то приму ваш ответ

Comment: в смысле плюсану)